# Java: How would I be able to get my program to draw in an Applet more efficiently?

Tags: java, applet, drawing, bufferedimage

Currently, I have been working on a project of my own that should display tiles that have been defined explicitly in a .txt file.

Each Tile object is represented by:

```
public Tile(final int x, final int y, final int z, final boolean walkable, final BufferedImage image)
```

In the snippet below, I am drawing each BufferedImage associated with each Tile, but the drawing process is so lengthy that I wonder if something else can be done to reduce strain?

```
private void redrawTiles(Graphics2D g, final Tile[][] mapTiles, final int width, final int height) {
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
    if (mapTiles == null) return;
    final float size = mapSize / 100f;
    for (Tile[] mt : mapTiles) {
        for (Tile t : mt) {
            g.drawImage(t.getImage(), (int) (t.getX() * 20 * size), (int) (t.getY() * 20 * size), (int) (getWidth() * size),
                    (int) (getHeight() * size), null);
        }
    }
}
```

The issue seems to have to do with the double foreach, as when I check the time it takes to go through it all, it averages around 1,500 milliseconds. Would combining all of the bufferedImages into one bufferedImage that I draw on the screen be more efficient?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: sorry it was originally a boolean method but I changed it to void for this question as the return value has little to nothing to do with the question

Comment: You may not be posting enough information to allow others to help you.

Comment: The issue seems to have to do with the double foreach, as when I check the time it takes to go through it all, it averages around 1,500 milliseconds. Would combining all of the bufferedImages into one bufferedImage that I draw on the screen be more efficient?

Comment: This question could be an [XY Problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem) in disguise where you ask how to solve a specific code problem when the best solution is to use a completely different approach. Is this a Swing app? AWT? Why not create a grid of JLabels that each hold their own "tile" ImageIcon for your background? And then change Icons whenever a grid cell needs to change its image?

Comment: Are all of your tiles changing for each redraw? If not, then don't redraw the tiles that are actually changing. Also, make sure you don't draw outside the visible area of the screen. Generally, painting one large image is faster than many small ones. And the image type must match that of the screen (`createCompatibleImage()`) for best performance. Is `t.getImage()` returning a static image, or is it computed each time? Finally, I agree with @HovercraftFullOfEels, you should provide some more code and context.

Comment: PS: I obviously meant *don't redraw the tiles that **are not** actually changing*. :-)

Comment: I've been able to resolve the issue. What I was doing wrong was I was using `getWidth()` and `getHeight()` for the width and height of the image I was drawing, which was actually using the width and height of the component I was drawing on. This would, in effect, draw huge images that couldn't be noticed because they were being overlapped by the other images being drawn.